# Query error int/varchar LEFTJOIN

Tags: mysql, php, mariadb

Can someone tell me what´s wrong with this query?

```
$sql = "select 
bans.id as banid,
bans.type,
bans.data,
bans.reason,
bans.expire,
bans.added_by,
bans.added_date,
players.id as playerid,
players.username,
FROM bans 
LEFT JOIN players
ON cast(players.id as varchar(50)) = bans.added_by                       
WHERE `bans.id` LIKE '%".$amount."%' OR 
`bans.added_by` LIKE '%".$amount."%' OR 
`bans.data` LIKE '%".$amount."%' OR 
`players.username` LIKE '%".$amount."%' OR 
`bans.data` LIKE '%".$usernamevanamount."%' OR 
`bans.reason` LIKE '%".$amount."%' 
ORDER BY bans.added_date DESC"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, insert query failed with:' . mysql_error());`

players.id = int

bans.added_by = varchar(50)
```

> **Error:**
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM bans LEFT JOIN players ON cast(players.id as varchar(50)) =
>   bans.added_by ' at line 11

Comment: Flagging as 'too localized' since it's a typo problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the comma character before the FROM: `player.username, FROM bans`.

Comment: Good spot. Hehe

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(50)) = bans.added_by WHERE `bans.id` LIKE '%Calvi' at line 13

I get that now, seems like there is still one error left :P

Comment: @user1857116 s/varchar/char/ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: @jynus Can you further explain what that means?